# Sending data from Sails Service to a Controller

Tags: javascript, httprequest, sails.js

I'm writing a pretty basic HTTP request using SailsJS. I'm getting the data I want from the api that I'm calling, but I can't figure out how to pass it from my service back to the controller and eventually respond to the request with the data in the body.

Here's my controller:

```
module.exports = {
    retrieve: function(req, res) {
        var output = AccountService.retrieveAccountInfo();
        console.log(output);
        return res.send(output);
    }
}
```

And here is my service that I'm calling.

```
module.exports = {

    retrieveAccountInfo: function() {
        var http = require('http');

        var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8280,
            path: '/sample/account?id=1',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'sample': 'header'
            }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            var data = '';
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers) + '\n\n');
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
                data += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                console.log('hit the end');
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            });
        });

        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        });

        req.end();
    }
}
```

I'm probably missing some basic JavaScript stuff here. I can get to the end callback and print "hit the end" as expected, but I can't get the data returned to the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the method you're using in your service is an **asynchronous** method, you can modify them like following

```
module.exports = {
    retrieve: function(req, res) {
        AccountService.retrieveAccountInfo(function(error, output) {
            console.log(output);
            return res.send(output);
        });
    }
}
```

service - use callback method

```
module.exports = {

    retrieveAccountInfo: function(callback) {
        var http = require('http');

        //.....

        res.on('end', function() {
             console.log('hit the end');
             callback(null, JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        //.....

        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            callback(e); //error
        });

        req.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I'm still getting used to the idea of callbacks. This makes much more sense now.